# Error with IRTtwin() function in BayesTwin package in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I am having problems with the `IRTtwin()` function in the `BayesTwin` package as I am trying to make structural equation modelling heritability analysis.

I have instralled the prerequired MCMC programme JAGS and have my monozygotic and dizygotic data in matrix form:

`data_mz_matrix`:

```
        [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  634.4647  642.4464
[2,]  561.5495  566.8142
[3,]  385.6539  297.9013
[4,]  869.0902  742.9749
[5,]  325.7212  456.9224
[6,]  552.7495  530.1064
[7,]  752.8985  785.5980
[8,]  607.7821  642.9311
[9,]  456.7949  587.5448
[10,]  495.3535  531.2442
[11,]  580.4959  600.7064
[12,]  335.6265  402.4331
[13,]  330.6488  297.3229
[14,]  798.6385  729.6208
[15,]  610.7475  593.2818
[16,]  667.3295  594.6006
[17,]  841.5771  749.7168
[18,]  341.1820  338.2659
[19,]  791.7964  836.9477
[20,]  958.9826  895.7239
```

and `data_dz_matrix`:

```
        [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  466.2194  469.7429
[2,]  644.1765  475.0217
[3,]  328.8530  320.8491
[4,]  499.0331  739.5708
[5,]  567.1459  470.8932
[6,]  511.2026  653.5025
[7,]  468.4694  431.9838
[8,]  852.7760  841.8387
[9,]  309.8622  337.3690
[10,]  372.1628  394.3338
[11,]  430.8337  522.0859
[12,]  376.8690  371.3945
[13,]  458.4320  315.7657
[14,]  809.8927  732.3091
[15,]  726.7737  626.1328
[16,]  395.0617  263.7908
[17,]  417.1143  463.6407
[18,]  896.6494 1136.7362
[19,]  663.7533  798.1774
[20,] 1052.3621  837.5557
```

When I run the `IRTtwin()` function I get the following error:

```
IRTtwin(data_mz = data_mz_matrix,data_dz = data_dz_matrix,
    twin1_datacols_p = c(1), twin2_datacols_p = c(2),
    twin1_datacols_cov = NA, twin2_datacols_cov = NA,
    decomp_model = "ACE", irt_model = "1PL", ge = FALSE,
    n_iter = 5000, n_burnin = 7000, n_chains = 1,
    fit_stats = FALSE, var_prior = "INV_GAMMA",
    N_cov = 0, inits = NA, Nk = 0)




> IRTtwin(data_mz = data_mz_matrix,data_dz = data_dz_matrix,
+         twin1_datacols_p = c(1), twin2_datacols_p = c(2),
+         twin1_datacols_cov = NA, twin2_datacols_cov = NA,
+         decomp_model = "ACE", irt_model = "1PL", ge = FALSE,
+         n_iter = 5000, n_burnin = 7000, n_chains = 1,
+         fit_stats = FALSE, var_prior = "INV_GAMMA",
+         N_cov = 0, inits = NA, Nk = 0)
Caution! To use this package, you need to install the MCMC program JAGS
    which can be freely obtained at http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net. 

Error in IRTtwin(data_mz = data_mz_matrix, data_dz = data_dz_matrix, twin1_datacols_p = c(1),  : 
You need phenotypic data at item level to run the analysis! It is not possible to analyse sum scores
```

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong to get this error message:
"You need phenotypic data at item level to run the analysis!"

Thanks in advance!